# недопустимый литеральный суффикс "d"

Tags: c++, c

Подскажите пожалуйста, подключил onde-header библиотеку, попытался скомпилировать, но VS2022 выдает ошибку:

> Ошибка    C3688   недопустимый литеральный суффикс "d"; не удалось найти
> литеральный оператор или шаблон литерального оператора "operator ""d"

на строке:

```
const int tick = (int)((input / pips_size) + 0.5d);
```

Никогда не работал с double и float, но, как я понимаю тут литерал "d" должен означать, что 0.5 должен быть приведен к double ?
Или что означает этот литерал и почему VS2022 выдает ошибку ?

Нагуглить про литерал "d" - так и не удалось.

Comment: Очень похоже на [литерал дня месяца](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/operator%22%22d), но он у вас почему-то применен к действительному значению... `d` для указания `double` не применяется; числа с плавающей точкой *без* каких-либо букв автоматом рассматриваются как имеющие тип `double`.

Comment: @Harry, Спасибо.  Но даже подключив: #include <chrono> using namespace std::literals::chrono_literals; VS2022 - все равно выдает ошибку.

Comment: не ищите. в стандарте литералы для чисел с точкой только  `f`,`F`,`l` и `L`

Comment: @AlexGlebe, а почему по этой ссылке https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/operator%22%22d - указан литерал "d" ? И как тогда код автора либы вообще у него работает ?

Comment: Интересно бы посмотреть весь код. Может, это какой-то пользовательский литерал...

Comment: @Harry, но если это пользовательский литерал, то ошибки не должно же быть ?

Comment: Тот оператор принимает на вход `unsigned long long`

Comment: Не должно, но вдруг просто какой `#define` не прописан? :)

Comment: по ссылке, что вы предложили рассматривается для целочисленных типов и в стандарте C++20. Вы проверяли число с точкой. Любые приколы компиляторов обернутся боком когда-нибудь. Не используйте нестандарт. Стандарт говорит : `none -> double`

Comment: @user7860670, извините, не могли бы Вы чуть подробнее пояснить, что значит "Тот оператор принимает на вход unsigned long long" ? На какой вход ?

Comment: Я имел ввиду аргумент оператора по ссылке https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/operator%22%22d

Comment: @Harry, если бы не было define`а, то, тогда бы либа сама по себе бы была нерабочая изначально получается.

Comment: Да не хотите показывать весь код - я и не претендую, без вопросов...

Comment: @Harry, я просто не понимаю, какую часть кода показывать. Там же его много.

Comment: Просто выложите весь код. Все сразу станет понятно.

Comment: Есть вариант выложить код в файлообменник и дать ссылку.